# "nomachine conflicts with nxserver" error when trying to install nomachine, even though nxserver not installed

Tags: linux, rhel, rhel5, nomachine-nx, nomachine

I am trying to install `nomachine` on my redhat (RHEL5 64 bit desktop) and I am getting the following error

> nomachine conflicts with nxserver

Same error occur while installing `nxnode` and `nxclient`.

Neither `nxserver`, nor `nxnode` nor `nxcliend` are installed and I still get the error.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: are you positive `nxserver` is not installed? what is the output of `rpm -qa |grep nxserver`?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the freenx packages that are probably shipped with Red Hat.

```
# rpm -e nxserver
```

Comment: It says cannot execute '/usr/NX/scripts/setup/nxserver.uninstall --uninstall' : File doesn't exists.

Comment: to get the uninstall file i'll need to independently install nxserver. But the problem is that i am unable to locate the nxserver folder, and its not letting me install it.